# SimpleDateFormat in Android giving unwanted time zone in Android 1.6

Tags: java, android, date

Given the following:

```
String dt = "Wed Jan 1 12:34:03 2010";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");
Date output = sdf.parse(dt);
```

Produces:

```
Wed Jan 1 12:34:03 ADT 2010
```

Where is the timezone coming from?  I don't have z in my format pattern.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're apparently displaying the `toString()` outcome of the `Date` object like as

```
System.out.println(output);
```

The format is specified in the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) and it indeed includes the timezone.

> ### toString
>
> ```
> public String toString()
> ```
>
> Converts this `Date` object to a `String` of the form:
>
> ```
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```

You need [`SimpleDateFormat#format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) to convert the obtained `Date` object to a `String` in the desired format before representing it. For example,

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(output);
System.out.println(s); // 01-01-2010 12:34:03
```

Answer (score 0):

When a Date object is created, the timezone is set from the system settings.

try output.getTimeZoneoffset() and it returns the offset in minutes (for ADT it's -180)